# How to get S-1 form from SEC using python?

Tags: python, pandas, edgar

I am trying to get S-1 balance sheets, income statements, etc. using Python. I've used a lot of packages (sec_api, edgar and others) trying to get the data, but I haven't been able to get it.

Could you provide a package or script how to get  S-1 statements?

I am trying this code but it doesn't work for S-1:

```
import pandas as pd 
from sec_api import XbrlApi



API_KEY= *

xbrlApi = XbrlApi(API_KEY)

url_s1_grdn = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1802255/000119312523250013/d492014ds1.htm'

grdn_xbrl_json = xbrlApi.xbrl_to_json(htm_url=url_s1_grdn)
# convert XBRL-JSON of income statement to pandas dataframe
def get_income_statement(xbrl_json):
    income_statement_store = {}

    # iterate over each US GAAP item in the income statement
    for usGaapItem in xbrl_json['StatementsOfIncome']:
        values = []
        indicies = []

        for fact in xbrl_json['StatementsOfIncome'][usGaapItem]:
            # only consider items without segment. not required for our analysis.
            if 'segment' not in fact:
                index = fact['period']['startDate'] + '-' + fact['period']['endDate']
                # ensure no index duplicates are created
                if index not in indicies:
                    values.append(fact['value'])
                    indicies.append(index)                    

        income_statement_store[usGaapItem] = pd.Series(values, index=indicies) 

    income_statement = pd.DataFrame(income_statement_store)
    # switch columns and rows so that US GAAP items are rows and each column header represents a date range
    return income_statement.T 


income_statement_grdn = get_income_statement(grdn_xbrl_json)


print("Income statement of Guardian Pharmacy Services 2022 S-1 filing as dataframe")
print('---------------------------------------------------------')
income_statement_grdn
```

Comment: you forgot `print()` in last line `print( income_statement_grdn )`

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error? Show it in question (not in comments) as text (not image). Do you get wrong values? Show what you get and what you expected. Don't expect that we will run code to see problem. Besides it can't work correctly on our computers

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: The result I get `Exception: API error: 404 - {"status":404,"message":"The filer did not attach XBRL data to the filing. A conversion is not possible."}`, but when I use a company like Apple, everything works fine, I don't know if the issue is related to the form itself

Comment: try with more companies - to see if there are more companies with the problem. But I think this company simply doesn't send data. Did you compare original HTML for `Apple` and `S-1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The S-1 filing in question doesn't have XBRL data attached which is necessary for a successful conversion and access to its financial statements. Consequently the XBRL-to-JSON Converter API returns an empty response, specifically a 424 error stating "The filer did not attach XBRL data to the filing. A conversion is not possible.". This is because the S-1 filing doesn't include structured XBRL data.

Please note that not all S-1 filings are released with structured XBRL data.

You can always make a manual check if a filing (e.g. S-1) has XBRL data by visiting the filing's details page.

Given your S-1 URL

> https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1802255/000119312523250013/d492014ds1.htm

simply replace the last part `d492014ds1.htm` with the accession number from the URL `000119312523250013`, add two hyphens `-` and `-index.html` to get `0001193125-23-250013-index.html`.

The filing's details page URL is:

> https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1802255/000119312523250013/0001193125-23-250013-index.html

[image]

Now let's look at another S-1 filing that has XBRL data attached to it:

> https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1021917/000149315223043907/forms-1.htm

Filing's details page:

> https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1021917/000149315223043907/0001493152-23-043907-index.htm

[image]